# Failed to parse the JSON, using rest Assured JSON PATH when using Multiple Threads

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured, jsonpath, rest-assured-jsonpath

**Trying to Automate an API. which is working fine, when using a single thread. But encountering the below exception when using multiple threads.**

**Exception occurring even when the method is synchronized**

com.jayway.restassured.path.json.exception.JsonPathException: Failed to parse the JSON document
at com.jayway.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$ExceptionCatcher.invoke(JsonPath.java:928)
at com.jayway.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$4.doParseWith(JsonPath.java:893)
at com.jayway.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$JsonParser.parseWith(JsonPath.java:972)
at com.jayway.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.get(JsonPath.java:201)
at com.jayway.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$get$0.call(Unknown Source)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.path(RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.groovy:392)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsImpl.path(RestAssuredResponseOptionsImpl.java:195)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:510)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:211)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:170)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:104)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

*EDIT*:
Below the code where is showing the error.The error where ever we are using Jsopath by restassured

```
sAccessToken = RestAssured.given()
                    .header("Authorization",
                            "Basic " + authkey)
                    .formParam("grant_type", "client_credentials").when().post(sEndPoint).then().statusCode(200)
                    .extract().path("access_token");
```

Comment: Don't have enough to debug, you need add code and request & response log.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.